# How to add some constraints or limits to a property?

Tags: modeling

Basically, I'm trying to make an asteroid field, so I want my component rocks to have varying sizes and shapes. So I'm using a displacement modifier on it, and I want to modulate its strength.
Like keep it's value between 1 and 1.5, how do I do that in blender?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
import bpy, random

def rand(a,b):
    return random.uniform(a, b) 


bpy.app.driver_namespace["rand"] = rand
```

Add a driver to your value like this:

[image]

> Note: you have to run the script once so that the driver value can
> work.

Comment: thanks for the answer @Chris, one q though, I've actually never run a script before(I'm not a beginner, but definitely not an expert), so is there any way to implement what you've done with simpler functions? otherwise, still thanks and I'll try out your method

Comment: you could use geometry nodes or animation nodes, then you wouldn't have to use python....

Comment: geometry nodes? well okay, that's something i think i've done before, I'll try it out, thx